# Which is the proper taylor series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

My friend and I are trying to tackle the following problem:

*Write the Taylor series around a = 1 for* $xe^{x}$

I approached the problem the following way:

We know that Taylor series for $e^x$ around 1 are:

$f(x) = e^{x} = \Sigma \frac{e^{1}}{n!}(x-1)^{n}$

so if we do g(x) = $xe^{x}$, $g(x) = x(f(x))$ and

$ g(x) = x(\Sigma \frac{e}{n!}(x-1)^{n}) = \Sigma x\frac{e}{n!}(x-1)^{n}$ from n = 0 to infinty

Which, according to WolframAlpha, leads back to $xe^{x}$.

Now, my friend did it the following way: 
he found f(x) of $xe^{x}$, and then f'(x)=$xe^{x}+e^{x}$, and then f''(x) = $xe^{x} + e^{x} + e^{x}$, and so forth (each iteration added another $e^{x}$). He came up with the following expression:

$\Sigma (n+1)\frac{e(x-1)^{n}}{n!}$ from n=0 to infinity.

I put both equations on a graph and they both seem to approximate $xe^{x}$ fairly well around a=1. **So my question is, who has the most acceptable Taylor Series? Is the other answer wrong?**

Comment: The first one is not a Taylor expansion; besides constants, only powers of $(x-1)$ are allowed to appear in the Taylor series here. So rewrite the $x$ in there as $(x-1)+1$, collect like terms and see what happens.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg may I ask why only powers of (x-1) are allowed to appear? In my book, an example for e^x around a=2 is given, and the expression for that is $\Sigma\frac{e^{2}}{n!}(x-2)^n$  , so I assumed I could just switch the a=2 for a=1 and multiply it all by x.

Comment: The definition of a Taylor series of a function around a point is to have a power series with terms only around that point. So use what the first comment says and write $x$ as $(x-1)+1$ now multiply as you did and see what comes up

Comment: @LauraSalas: For a Taylor series around $a$, the general term is of the form $(\text{some number}) \cdot (x-a)^n$. So yes, in a Taylor series around $2$, only powers of $(x-2)$ appear; in a Taylor series around $0$, only powers of $x$ appear; and in the Taylor series around $1$ you are looking for, only powers of $(x-1)$ should appear. The series you found is nice, it's just not a Taylor series, but as said should easily be converted into one. You can think about whether your method plus that conversion would work for other functions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Taylor series are a special case of *power series*, which are expressions of the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n=a_0+a_1(x-x_0)+\frac12a_2(x-x_0)^2+\dots.$$
What this means is that all the terms in the sum must look like a constant multiplied by a power of $(x-x_0)$. The expression
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e}{n!}x(x-1)^n$$
does indeed converge to $xe^x$ (you are correct about this), and it is a series representation of $xe^x$, but it is not the *Taylor series* expansion---as the terms don't look like $(x-1)^n$. The extra factor of $x$ makes this into not-a-Taylor-series. One way to work around this is to write
$$\begin{split}xe^x&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e}{n!}(x-1+1)(x-1)^n\\&=e\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}(x-1)^{n+1}+e\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}(x-1)^n\\&=e\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(x-1)^n+e\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}(x-1)^n\\
&=e+e\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+1}{n!}(x-1)^n\\&=e\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{n!}(x-1)^n.\end{split}$$
This is the correct Taylor series representation of $xe^x$.